# while executing the tcpdump command in RobotFramework getting error

Tags: python, linux, robotframework

I am executing the below command in RobotFramework,

```
execute "tcpdump -i any port ${port} -vvv -n -w /opt/admin/test.20200309.pcap &" on device "${host}"
```

I am getting the error:-
FAIL    SubCommandFailure: ('Command execution failed', TimeoutError("timeout occurred:\ntimeout value: 60\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the server issue not able to collect the log